# Magento 2 get filter list

Tags: filter, magento2

I have Magento 2.4.3

I want to get filter list because i want to print price range list in to onother my section of site. (TopMenu.php)

[image]

I tried:

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$stateFilter = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList');
$selectedFilters = $stateFilter->getFilters();
foreach($selectedFilters as $filter){
    $html .=  $filter->getName(); 
    $html .=  $filter->getLabel(); 
}
```

But i get this error:

```
 Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface
```

How can I get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$filterableAttributes = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);

$layerResolver = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
$filterList = $objectManager->getInstance()->create(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
        [
            'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
        ]
    );      

    $layer = $layerResolver->get();
    $filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
    $maxPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
    $minPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();  

    $i = 0;
    $filterAttrs = [];
    $html .= '<ul>';
foreach($filters as $filter)
{
    $values = [];
    $attr_code = (string)$filter->getRequestVar();
    $attr_label = (string)$filter->getName();

    if(strtolower($filter->getName())=='price')
    {
       
        $html .= (string)$filter->getName();

        $items = $filter->getItems(); 
        
            foreach($items as $item)
            {
                    $html .= '<li>';
                            $html .= '<a href="/onepage/?price='.$item->getValue().'">';
                                $html .=$item->getLabel();
                            $html .= '</a>';

                    $html .= '</li>';
            }
    }

 
    

}  
$html .= '</ul>';
```